# Using own apt mirror with apt. apt update try to connect to prod.debian.map.fastly.net istead of deb.debian.org

Tags: linux, debian, dns, apt

I create own apt mirror available locally for all servers.
To not change **/etc/apt/sources.list** I also run dnsmasq, that resolve **deb.debian.org (and security.debian.org)** to private IP address, where apt mirror is running.

So apt mirror **client** configuration:

```
root@apt-client:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.14.122.165
root@apt-client:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list| grep -v '^#'

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free

root@apt-client:~# ping deb.debian.org
PING deb.debian.org (10.14.122.165) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from deb.debian.org (10.14.122.165): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.317 ms
^C
--- deb.debian.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.317/0.317/0.317/0.000 ms
root@apt-client:~# ping security.debian.org
PING security.debian.org (10.14.122.165) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from deb.debian.org (10.14.122.165): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms
^C
--- security.debian.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.274/0.274/0.274/0.000 ms
root@apt-client:~# apt update
0% [Connecting to prod.debian.map.fastly.net (151.101.12.204)] [Connecting to prod.debian.map.fastly.net (151.101.12.204)]
```

I don't know why apt try to connect to **prod.debian.map.fastly.net** istead of **deb.debian.org**. In /etc/apt.sources.list I have **deb.debian.org**. Ping shows that **deb.debian.org** is resolved for local address: **10.14.122.165** and apt should connect there.

apt mirror server and dnsmasq server it's the same server with IP: **10.14.122.165**

```
root@apt-client# host deb.debian.org
deb.debian.org has address 10.14.122.165
deb.debian.org is an alias for debian.map.fastly.net.
debian.map.fastly.net has IPv6 address 2a04:4e42:3::645
deb.debian.org is an alias for debian.map.fastly.net.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that APT uses SRV records to look up hostnames in a round-robin if they're available.  This solves two problems:

- If a DNS round-robin is used, then a user may connect to one host which is up to date to download manifests and then connect to another host which hasn't been updated yet, causing failures.
- For HTTPS servers, it's difficult to use a single generic hostname because multiple different parties would either have to share a certificate or issue their own certificates for the same name.

So when you look up the DNS entries, you also need to look up SRV records:

```
$ host -t srv _http._tcp.deb.debian.org
_http._tcp.deb.debian.org has SRV record 10 1 80 prod.debian.map.fastly.net.
$ host -t srv _https._tcp.deb.debian.org
_https._tcp.deb.debian.org has SRV record 10 1 443 debian.map.fastly.net.
```

You'll either need to override those or return NXDOMAIN upon receiving a query for them.

Comment: This is exacly what I need. I configure dnsmasq to resolve this addresses and now this is working. Thank You very much.

Comment: @LukaszCzyzewski Since this answered the question and solved your issue, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer to your question so bk2204 gets credit for it.